# Is it possible to fake the query-string on postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I have ASP.NET page which has a security-sensitive query string. In order to verify it I perform quite heavy calculations in `Page_Load`. That page has a button and `OnClick` handler.

Do I still need to verify the query string again if `IsPostBack` is true?

Comment: Yes. Any data in a HTTP request can be forged. If you have sensitive information then store it server-side and reference it by an opaque token such as the session ID (i.e. use `Session`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In fact almost everything is subject to forgery.

The query string can easily be changed, from the browser itself, the source code, man-in-the-middle attacks, etc.

It is even better to avoid putting sensitive data in the query string, try to use `POST` as much as possible. (A `GET` is allowed to be send cross-domain, while POST isn't)